# Getting issue using accordion in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-accordion

I have created accordion with plus and minus as shown below image.

[image]but i am clicking first accordion then other accordion div are jumbling and getting unwanted space as shown below image.

[image]

Reference Link(check the below link for sample code of problem):
bootsnipp.com/nageswar/snippets/e3RBD

My Code:

```
body {
  font-family: 'open sans';
}
#accordion-first .accordion-group {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#accordion-first .accordion-heading,
#accordion-first .accordion-toggle:hover,
#accordion-first .accordion-heading .accordion-toggle.active {
  background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
}
#accordion-first .accordion-heading {
  border-bottom: 0px none;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#accordion-first .accordion-heading .accordion-toggle {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 0px !important;
  color: #222;
  outline: medium none !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#accordion-first .accordion-heading .accordion-toggle.active em {
  background-color: #F7C221;
}
#accordion-first .accordion-heading .accordion-toggle > em {
  background-color: #222;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 32px;
}
```

html:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu" style="overflow-y: scroll; padding: 1% 4%; overflow-x: hidden; display: none; opacity: 1;">
  <li class="col-sm-8">
    <ul>
      <li class="dropdown-header" style="color: #323232;font-weight:bold;padding-left:15px;">Services</li>
      <li class="col-sm-12">
        <div id="accordion-first accordion-custom" class="clearfix">
          <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
            <div class="accordion-group col-sm-4">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false">
                  <em class="icon-fixed-width fa fa-plus" href="#collapseOne"></em>
                </a>
                <a href="http://www.google.com">
                  <i class="fa fa-gears service-menu-icon"></i>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div style="height: 0px;" id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Software Development Services</li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/it-outsourcing-services/outsource-software-application-development-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Software Application Development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/it-outsourcing-services/outsource-web-application-development-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Web Application Development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/it-outsourcing-services/outsource-mobile-application-development-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mobile Application Development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/it-outsourcing-services/outsource-saas-development-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Saas Application Development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/it-outsourcing-services/outsource-software-testing-quality-assurance-qa-service.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Software Testing Quality Assurance</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/it-outsourcing-services/outsource-cloud-computing-application-development-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cloud Computing Application Development</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">IT Solution by Platforms</li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/it-outsourcing-services/outsource-android-application-development-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Android Application Development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/it-outsourcing-services/outsource-azure-application-development-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Azure Application Development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/it-outsourcing-services/c-plus-plus-application-development-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> C/C++ Application Development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/it-outsourcing-services/html5-application-development-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> HTML5 Application Development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/it-outsourcing-services/outsource-ios-ipad-iphone-application-development-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> iOS Application Development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/it-outsourcing-services/outsource-java-application-development-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Java Application Development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/it-outsourcing-services/outsource-linux-unix-application-development-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Linux/UNIX Software Development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/it-outsourcing-services/outsource-dot-net-application-development-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> .NET Application Development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/it-outsourcing-services/outsource-php-application-development-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> PHP Application Development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/it-outsourcing-services/outsource-python-application-development-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Python Application Development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/it-outsourcing-services/outsource-ruby-on-rails-ror-web-application-development-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Ruby on Rails Application Development</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br style="clear:both">
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group col-sm-4">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false">
                  <em class="icon-fixed-width fa fa-plus"></em>
                </a>
                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-gears service-menu-icon"></i></a>
              </div>
              <div style="height: 0px;" id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="http://www.example.net/finance-accounting-bpo/outsource-accounts-payable-services.php"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Accounts Payable</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/finance-accounting-bpo/outsource-accounts-receivable-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Accounts Receivable</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/finance-accounting-bpo/outsource-bookkeeping-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Accounting and Bookkeeping</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/finance-accounting-bpo/outsource-financial-analysis-reporting-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Financial Analysis Reporting</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/finance-accounting-bpo/outsource-cfo-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> CFO Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/finance-accounting-bpo/outsource-insurance-claims-processing-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Insurance Claims Processing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/finance-accounting-bpo/outsource-mortgage-process-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mortgage Process Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/finance-accounting-bpo/outsource-payroll-processing-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Payroll Processing Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/finance-accounting-bpo/outsource-tax-preparation-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Tax Preparation Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/finance-accounting-bpo/outsource-real-estate-title-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Real Estate Title Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/finance-accounting-bpo/outsource-record-to-report-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Record to Report Services</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br style="clear:both">
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group col-sm-4">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false">
                  <em class="icon-fixed-width fa fa-plus"></em>
                </a>
                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-file-text service-menu-icon"></i></a>
              </div>
              <div style="height: 0px;" id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/outsource-data-entry-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Data Entry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/data-entry/outsource-data-processing-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Data Processing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/data-entry/outsource-data-conversion-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Data Conversion</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/data-entry/outsource-ocr-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> OCR</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/data-entry/outsource-data-cleansing-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Data Cleansing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/data-entry/outsource-database-development-migration-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Database Management</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/outsource-catalog-management-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Catalog Management</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/outsource-data-management-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Data Management</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/outsource-research-data-mining-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Data Mining</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br style="clear:both">
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group col-sm-4">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false">
                  <em class="icon-fixed-width fa fa-plus"></em>
                </a>
                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-phone service-menu-icon"></i></a>
              </div>
              <div style="height: 0px;" id="collapseFour" class="accordion-body collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">By Industry</li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/call-center-outsourcing/banking-financial-services-insurance-bfsi-industry-call-center-services.php" style="padding-top:6px;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> BFSI</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/call-center-outsourcing/energy-utilities-industry-call-center-services.php" style="padding-top:6px;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Energy and Utilities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/call-center-outsourcing/government-agencies-call-center-services.php" style="padding-top:6px;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Government Agencies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/call-center-outsourcing/healthcare-industry-call-center-services.php" style="padding-top:6px;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Medical and Healthcare</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/call-center-outsourcing/automotive-industry-call-center-services.php" style="padding-top:6px;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Automotive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/call-center-outsourcing/logistics-transportation-industry-call-center-services.php" style="padding-top:6px;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Logistics, Supply Chain and Transportation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/call-center-outsourcing/manufacturing-industry-call-center-services.php" style="padding-top:6px;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Manufacturing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/call-center-outsourcing/real-estate-industry-call-center-services.php" style="padding-top:6px;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Real Estate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/call-center-outsourcing/retail-ecommerce-industry-call-center-services.php" style="padding-top:6px;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Retail and eCommerce</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/call-center-outsourcing/telecom-industry-call-center-services.php" style="padding-top:6px;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Telecom</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/call-center-outsourcing/media-entertainment-industry-call-center-services.php" style="padding-top:6px;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Media and Entertainment</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/call-center-outsourcing/travel-leisure-hospitality-industry-call-center-services.php" style="padding-top:6px;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Travel, Leisure and Hospitality</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/call-center-outsourcing/education-institutions-call-center-services.php" style="padding-top:6px;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Education Institutions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/call-center-outsourcing/chemical-pharmaceutical-industry-call-center-services.php" style="padding-top:6px;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Chemical Pharmaceutical</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">By Services</li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/call-center-outsourcing/outsource-inbound-outbound-sales-customer-acquisition-services.php" style="padding-top:6px;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sales and Customer Acquisition</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/call-center-outsourcing/outsource-customer-care-call-center-services.php" style="padding-top:6px;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Customer Care</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/call-center-outsourcing/outsource-debt-collection-recovery-call-center-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Debt Collection</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/call-center-outsourcing/outsource-technical-support-helpdesk-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Technical Support / Helpdesk Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/call-center-outsourcing/outsource-call-center-support-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Call Center Support</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/call-center-outsourcing/outsource-multi-channel-call-center-support-services.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Multi-channel Support</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.example.net/call-center-outsourcing/call-center-technology.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Best-in-class Technology</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br style="clear:both">
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group col-sm-4">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" href="http://www.example.net/outsource-ecommerce-support-services.php">
                  <em class="icon-fixed-width fa fa-plus"></em>
                </a>
                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-gears service-menu-icon"></i></a>
              </div>
              <div style="height: 0px;" id="collapseFive" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                </div>
              </div>
              <br style="clear:both">
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group col-sm-4">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseSix" aria-expanded="false">
                  <em class="icon-fixed-width fa fa-plus"></em>
                </a>
                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-gears service-menu-icon"></i></a>
              </div>
              <div style="height: 0px;" id="collapseSix" class="accordion-body collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                </div>
              </div>
              <br style="clear:both">
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group col-sm-4">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseSeven" aria-expanded="false">
                  <em class="icon-fixed-width fa fa-plus"></em>
                </a>
                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-gears service-menu-icon"></i></a>
              </div>
              <div style="height: 0px;" id="collapseSeven" class="accordion-body collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                </div>
              </div>
              <br style="clear:both">
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group col-sm-4">
              <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseEight" aria-expanded="false">
                  <em class="icon-fixed-width fa fa-plus"></em>
                </a>
                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-gears service-menu-icon"></i></a>
              </div>
              <div style="height: 0px;" id="collapseEight" class="accordion-body collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                </div>
              </div>
              <br style="clear:both">
            </div>
            <br style="clear:both">
          </div>
          <!-- end accordion -->
          <br style="clear:both">
        </div>
        <br style="clear:both">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="col-sm-4">
    <ul>
      <li class="dropdown-header" style="color: #323232;font-weight:bold;">Perspectives on Services</li>
      <li><img width="300" height="200" title=" Download Customer Care case study and read how an Australian based manufacturing company increased sales and customer satisfaction after handling their customer care call center services by Invensis." alt="Invensis, a leading IT Services company, offers customer care call center services to clients globally. Download case study and read how an Australia based manufacturing company increased sales and customer satisfaction."
        src="http://www.example.net/assets/img/customer-care-call-center-outsourcing-services-indddvensis-technologies.png"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
(function($) {
  "use strict"

  // Accordion Toggle Items
  var iconOpen = 'fa fa-minus',
    iconClose = 'fa fa-plus';

  $(document).on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', '.accordion', function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target)
    $target.siblings('.accordion-heading')
      .find('em').toggleClass(iconOpen + ' ' + iconClose);
    if (e.type == 'show')
      $target.prev('.accordion-heading').find('.accordion-toggle').addClass('active');
    if (e.type == 'hide')
      $(this).find('.accordion-toggle').not($target).removeClass('active');
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What is the desired result? I think you need to use `position: absolute` on `.accordion-toggle`

Comment: Please create a working demo (like jsFiddle) that reproduces your problem or share a live link.

Comment: ok i will create and share with you

Comment: whenever i am clicking menu1 then other menu will jumble and if u menu 4 means unwanted gap. check the link http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/e3RBD

Comment: I can't see that, it requires me to login. can you make it public?

Comment: sorry for that check this link bootsnipp.com/nageswar/snippets/e3RBD

Comment: That doesn't look like your screenshot, it's a different code...?!!

Comment: but in this example has a same problem what i had in my screen like  whenever i am clicking menu1 then other menu will jumble and if u menu 4 means unwanted gap.if we resolve in this, that's helpful for me to resolve my problem.you got my point right?